# Android with Eclipse - If condition fails for some unknown reason. What am I missing?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, network-programming

I'm using this function to check if a given IP is in the subnet like so...

```
private void myFunc(String ssid, DhcpInfo dhcpInfo)
{
    //...
    if(ipInSubnet(targetIp, dhcpInfo.gateway, dhcpInfo.netmask))
    //...
}

private boolean ipInSubnet(String ip, int subnet, int netmask)
{
    try
    {
        InetAddress a = (InetAddress) InetAddress.getByName(ip);

        byte[] b = a.getAddress();
        int i = ((b[3] & 0xFF) << 24) + ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 16) + ((b[1] & 0xFF) << 8) + ((b[0] & 0xFF) << 0);
        int subnetMasked = subnet & netmask;
        int ipMasked = i & netmask;
        if(subnetMasked == ipMasked)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

What is weird is this line in the debugger

```
 if(subnetMasked == ipMasked)
```

During testing, stepping through in the debugger, both subnetMasked and ipMasked have the same value of 108736 and I would expect the function to return true. Unfortunately it never gets past the if statement above and always returns false.

What in the world could be going on here? is this some error in the compiler?

A clean and rebuild did not work and there is no exception caught.

Thanks for advance for any help, I feel like I'm missing something obvious or something very strange is going on.

Comment: try using conditional operator may be it might work for you if "IF" is not working properly (condition)?1:2;

Comment: or try it if(submet != ipmask){return  false ;}

Comment: We miss you Dave.

Comment: @Dave S come back to us

Comment: @Dave S we miss you

Comment: @Dave S Pool party when?

Comment: Dave, we miss you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to see here, I was getting lazy at the end of the day. After fixing the function it appeared to continue to return false because that is the line Eclipse was highlighting. It turns out this is just an error in the debugger and the function was indeed returning true. I could have saved a lot of time just hitting step over one more time. Hopefully someone learns from this and avoid the same mistake and wasted time.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that an exception may be occurring somewhere else in the code, maybe even in the underlying framework?

The values appear to be the same as they where when you checked them at the if section, since they've not changed, I suspect there may be a buried exception, that your not seeing, that's getting handled/cleared by the underlying framework.

Comment: No exceptions occur and both ints have the same value.

Comment: try changing the condition to something like
   (subnetMasked - ipMasked)==0 
to play with it... may be store the difference in varaible and see that